# What filesystem to use for a 10 TB drive connected to router with DD-WRT and Mac?

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, exfat, fat32, ext4

I am going to connect a hard drive to my router and let the router share the drive through SMB. The purpose is to backup my computers using Time Machine.

I realise that if I ever need to restore a large amount of data or have some issues with the drive, I might want to be able to connect it directly to one of my Macs. I am at loss about what filesystem I should use in such a situation.

Fat32 - doesn't support volumes larger than 2 TB
exFat - not (?) supported by DD-WRT (at least not out of the box)
Ext4 - very weak support in macos
NTFS - weak support in macos
APFS/HFS+ - weak or no support in DD-WRT

What are my options?

Comment: Do you mean a 10TB drive?  10GB seems like you're asking a question from the past...

Comment: Does your router even support APFS? or HFS+?  Are you Mac only?

Comment: The disks on a router are controlled by the routers OS and have nothing to do with macs. The Mac will only see the network protocol which will be SMB

Comment: @MrR You are right.

Comment: @MrR Yes, I am Mac only. Router support for HFS+ or APFS is weak. There seems to be workarounds but they are tedious and unreliable.

Comment: @mmmmmmm Yes I know but as I wrote I might want to connect the drive directly to a Mac too. Therefore I need an FS that can be used by both types of devices.

Comment: NOTE: FAT32 - it's 2TB partitions - so you could split your 10TB up into a number of 2TB partitions ... if you have multiple machines and say use 1 partition per machine to backup that way you don't have 1 mac dominating the backups (remember when Timemachine runs out of space it starts deleting old backups....).

Comment: OR perhaps hang the drive off one of your machines, rather than the router.  All the machines can still see the drive (via AFP) - then you can choose whatever format you want ??

Comment: Remember you also need a backup of that 10TB drive - so if you need to reformat to APFS then just reformat and then restore from the backup

Comment: @MrR The problem is that that machine then won't have a network backup but a local backup, and it seems to be impossible to convert a local backup to a network backup (I want to preserve backup history).

Comment: I've never looked (I've got an old airport extreme time machine somewhere I could check) but isn't the stuff that's written essentially the same whether writing on an attached disk, or a NAS attached disk?  If not then DD-WRT make the backup in a format that can be retrieved later if the router dies?  Alternatively what about [Mac shared as a Time Machine backup destination](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202784#mac)? That's not local (it's more like NAS, but not exactly).

Comment: @MrR Not sure I understand you but a network attached disk A can use any filesystem as long as the device B it is connected to can read it. B then serves A using, typically, SMB to a computer C. For C the only thing that matters is SMB, the filesystem on A is hidden by B.

Comment: @d-b Agreed.  However if you use file sharing - share that drive via SMB with the "Share as a Time Machine backup destination" (control click on folder name, then advanced options) - and then in time machine use that share as the destination - isn't that effectively the same as the router case [but with filesystem of your choice, even if physically same machine, but still a network backup??]

Comment: @MrR Hmm, never seen that option. Will try and see what happens.